# Python - Access Dictionary Inside Dictionary Inside of List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to sort a list of stocks by their name and their last trade(price),
but the way it's setup makes it difficult for me to figure out how to sort it from either smallest to highest or highest to smallest.

so the list is setup this way:

thelist = [list{dictionay1{dictonary2}}]

the dictionary inside the list:

```
{'symbol_id': 'APPL', 'time_exchange': '2018-10-24T22:44:36.5280358Z', 'ask_price': 610.67, 'bid_price': 610.45, 'last_trade': {'time_exchange': '2018-10-24T21:38:13.0000000Z', 'price': 608.99938084, 'size': 651.39819405, 'taker_side': 'BUY'}}
```

the list contains at least 400 of these dictionaries.

so i choose to loop like this:

```
stocks = ['APPL']

for item in thelist:
   name = item["symbol_id"]
   if name in stocks:
     price = round(item['last_trade']['price'], 2)
     print(name, price)
```

that prints the stocks with its last trade price, but how do i go about sorting something like that?

i've tried sorting with itemgetter but can't access the last_trade dictionary with that... any help?

Comment: `dict['last_trade']['price']` Have you tried something like this?

Comment: `sorted(my_dict_list,key=lambda item:item['last_trade']['price'])`

Comment: `[{{}}]` is an empty dict in a set in a list. Probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a key function that returns the dict value you want the sort order to be based on:

```
thelist.sort(key=lambda d: d['last_trade']['price'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [sorted()](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) function.

It allows you to specify a function as  the key parameter to sort an iterable by. You could call sorted() on your array and provide a key that sorts by the price of the last_trade of each element.